# Erlang: Why can't I register self()?

Tags: erlang

This line fails with a `badarg` exception:

```
register(myproc, self()),
```

The documentation says that `self/0` returns a pid and that `register/2` takes a pid. So what gives?

**Edit:** No, seriously, it's not already registered, it's not a reserved atom, and it works when I register it from the process that's spawning it.

Oh weird! Okay, I got some more clues. When I move the call to `register()` around to different places, sometimes it works and sometimes it breaks. Here's my sample code. Run it before you call me crazy. :-)

```
-module(pingpong).
-export([start/1,  ping/2, pong/0]).

ping(N, Pong_Pid) ->
    link(Pong_Pid), 
    pingr(N, Pong_Pid).

pingr(0, _) ->
    io:format("Ping exiting~n", []),
    exit(ping);

pingr(N, Pong_Pid) ->
    Pong_Pid ! {ping, self()},
    receive
        pong ->
            io:format("Ping received pong~n", [])
    end,
    pingr(N - 1, Pong_Pid).

pong() ->
    %% This one works.
    %%register(pong, self()),
    process_flag(trap_exit, true), 
    pongr().

pongr() ->
    %% This one fails.
    register(pong, self()),
    receive
        {ping, Ping_PID} ->
            io:format("Pong received ping~n", []),
            Ping_PID ! pong,
            pongr();
        {'EXIT', From, Reason} ->
            io:format("pong exiting, got ~p~n", [{'EXIT', From, Reason}])
    end.

start(Ping_Node) ->
    PongPID = spawn(pingpong, pong, []),
    spawn(Ping_Node, pingpong, ping, [3, PongPID]).
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the process is already registered, it will throw a badarg. There is also some other cases that causes this, like the name is already used. See [the erlang:register/2 docs](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#register-2) for more.

EDIT

It's great that you posted code to reproduce your problem.

So, the first time you enter `pongr/0` you will register `self()`. When you receive a message, you will process it and call `pongr/0` again. The second time you enter `pongr/0` you try to register `self()`, which fails because it's already registered.

Also, if you want to use register a large number of processes, you should look into [`gproc`](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc). `register/2` requires an atom as the key and there is a limit of around one million atoms, unless you explicitly change it. See the [efficiency guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html#id67006). `gproc` can also run distributed and may thus be used instead of the `global` module.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to offend you. See my edited answer for an explanation of the problem in your code.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, DUH!!! I'm almost embarrassed I didn't see it before. Also, thanks for the bonus tip and efficiency link.

Answer (score 6):

is myproc already registered?

first call should succeed, additional calls will cause badarg exception.

```
1> register(myproc, self()).
true
2> myproc ! foo.
foo
3> flush().
Shell got foo
ok
4> register(myproc, self()).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  register/2
        called as register(myproc,<0.30.0>)
```